# Performatic way to store data containing 2 fixed Chars and 4 digits in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sqldatatypes

We have to store a "file ID" information in a multi million rows table. The format is Brazilian State ID abbreviation (i.e.: PA for PARA, BA for Bahia, SP for Sao Paulo, RJ for Rio de Janeiro, and so on) and a "scope" information, built by a short format Year ie.: 19 for 2019 and month, resulting in i.e 'PA1908' format.

As said before, the table has multi million rows and every month we have to compare it's data with external data source, and in case the external data source is most update then our table, we must replace entire STATE-YEAR-MONTH records, so the file id exist just to be a param in the query's where clause in order to select rows to delete.

In the first modeling verion, I splitted file id in two columns, being fileid_state as Char(2) datatype using hash index and fileid_scope as smallint datatype, but I'm not sure this is the only way to archive acceptable performance, may be using just only one column named file_id with Char(6) datatype with hash index could be performatic as first version. Any suggestions how of two method is best, or another way to store file id in order to select rows for deleting as fast as possible?

Remember it's kind hard for me to benchmark the methods because we have almost 1 billion rows in a limited hardware.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl-name) and B) SHOW INDEX FROM (tbl-name);  for analysis.

Comment: The table has so many fields and create table command didn't fit in this comment field "too long by 2319 characters".

But, I haven't created the File ID field anyway, so the creation statement is useless in this case.

Comment: Please post results to pastebin.com (max is 1/2 M bytes in a file) and share the link with the community.  Can be used for SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW INDEX FROM into separate files on one day as GUEST.

Comment: I've created a gist: 
https://gist.github.com/gedean/b3475097989bbb13427c292e22221b0d

Comment: Mr. Dias, Thanks for the SHOW CREATE TABLE tabwin_base; posted to github.  Please identify the column name(s) for your StateID and short format yymm.  Also, did you forget to post TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM tabwin_base; so we can see your cardinality information?  From RJ's request, Please provide the planned UPDATE and SELECT statements that may need this index; we will critique.  Why would you delete a whole row when it is likely only a few columns in a row need to be modified for the current data? Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:  Datatype:  First ask yourself what will be done with the string:

- Do you ever need to look just at the 'state' part?  The 'year' part?  The 'month' part?  If you answer "yes" to any of those, then you should *probably* store the parts in 2 or 3 columns.  `state CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`, then use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for the numeric part(s).
- If no, the simply do `CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  If needed, this can be `INDEXed`, either by itself, or together with other column(s) in a "composite" index.  Please provide the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statements that may need this index; we will critique.

There is no "hash" indexing, only BTree.

"select rows for deleting as fast as possible" -- What percentage of the table will be deleted?  If, for example, you will `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE sym = 'PA1908'`, *and* it is only a small part of the table, then `INDEX(sym)` works optimally.

I say "ascii" so that you avoid the space/processing needed for utf8, etc.

Q2:  "is most update then our table, we must replace entire STATE-YEAR-MONTH records"  -- Please elaborate on what happens here.

Comment: Q1: I do need something like DELETE FROM my_table WHERE fileid = 'PA1908' OR DELETE FROM my_table WHERE fileid_state = 'PA' AND fileid_scope = 1908', specifying the state abbreviation, year and month in the WHERE clause.

Q2: is about the reason we have to delete outdated rows.

About hash index, my research got me to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html#hash-index-characteristics

Comment: @GedeanDias - The discussion of "hash" is poorly worded; it applies only to Engine=Memory.

Comment: @GedeanDias - If you are purging old data, the best approach is discussed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .  If you go that direction, be sure to use `PARTITION BY RANGE` and have "1908" as a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` as the "partition key".